# AS3 Flash duplicate movieclip cardgame

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, duplicates, movieclip

I'm working on a card game where you could create a deck out of a collection of cards. you can create a total of 3 differend decks.

The collection shows a array of objects, those objects hold:

- a movieclip (the card image + text fields)
- the text field value's
- and some aditional data in the form of strings.

Now when I click a card in the collection to be added to for example deck 1. I dont want it to get removed from the collection cause I like to use it in other decks too so instead I make a duplicate with the constructor method:

```
var tempClass:Class = Object(target).constructor;
var tempcard = new tempClass() as Object;
```

So the problem with this way of doing it is that whenever I take that deck into a match there's no real way to refer towards this card. Since every card in the deck is called tempcard.

Also I'm working on a drag drop system that let me drag 1 card from a spot in my deck towards another spot in my deck or swap 2 cards by dropping it on another card. All this "temp's will make the job extremely confusing and difficult.

any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class called 'Card' and extend it from MovieClip. In this class you should create a new property called 'id', which should be unique for every card. Store instances of these classes in your collection.

This way when you compare two cards, you should be able to easily identify which is which. I've put in some sample code below.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Card extends MovieClip
    {
        public var id:String;

        public function Card(cardID:String)
        {
            super();
            this.id = cardID;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: tnx for this answer, i didnt think about such a simple solution as making a id. Although i implemented it differendly from here. what i did was assign a  id to the original movieclip like this: `cardArray[i]._id = [i]` and than in the tempcard creator function i added this line: `tempcard._id = cardArray[i]._id.`